# MVC5 Validation Errors in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, model-view-controller

I am using MVC5 and having problem displaying the validation errors of an object both in the Validation Summary section and the individual validation messages for each control.

Lets put aside client validation for the moment although we have ENABLED IT in the web config and included the js files.

If a model that is invalid is passed to a view that has in place a Validation Summary (setting excludePropertyErrors to false)  and for each control there is a @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Summary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }), shoudn't all these display the Validation errors in the object when the page loads.

We checked the object and the framwork knows it is invlaid (ModelState.IsValid is definitely false) and the errors collection contains several validation errors 
(System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError) but none of them show up neither in the ValidationSummary or the ValidationMessage for the individual controls when the page loads.

Currently I am getting he validation errors manually by context.Entry(prop).GetValidationResult().ValidationErrors.ToList(); and passing it to the Viewbag and iterate over them in the view to display them. Seems crazy!

P.S. The main View is composed of several partial views in which the controls are and the Vaidationsummary is in the Main containing view.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProduct(id)
{
    var product= await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
    return View(product);
}
```

As I mentioned , there are NO VALIDATION MESSAGES ANYWHERE. If we turn off client side validation the input control html is

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="Price" name="Price" style="font-weight:bold" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

As you can see the value is empty BUT it says it is valid even though the field is a required field marked so via DataAnnotations and the Model is INVALID and includes validation error that Price field is required!

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
<div class="col-sm-5">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "font-weight:bold" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the generated html with client side validation enabled :

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." data-val-required="The Price field is required." id="Price" name="Price" style="font-weight:bold" type="text" value="">
```

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Post some code for better understanding...

Comment: And some html generated for an input and associated validation message

Comment: Show the code you use in the generate the above input and its associated validation, and the code when you dont turn off client side validation

Comment: You code for the view looks fine. Is the problem that the error does not show when you submit? You mentioned _when page loads_ Validation errors don't show initially, only when you edit with an invalid value or submit the form

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our business logic requires that an Invalid Product should be saveable. So we have disabled validation on save on the dbcontext. When the object is viewed later, I would like to show all the validation errors both in the validation summary and the individual controls.

Comment: I guess in your GET method, you could call `TryValidateModel(yourModel);` before `return View(yourModel)` which would display the validation messages. You might only do this if the model actually exists in the database (not in a Create form).

Comment: Many thanks. This sorted out the validationsummary. i.e. all the errors are now displayed there. However, as far the individual fields are concerned, some have the error messages and some don't even though ALL the errors are listed in the validationsummary!

Comment: Obvious cause is that the name of the control and its associated validation message tag don't match but if your always using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty, ...)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` then should not be a problem. Perhaps try the overload first overload of `ValidationMessageFor` (without the `validationMessage` and `htmlAttributes` parameters). Not sure why you need to add another class anyway since you can style it using the class names generated by the helper.

Comment: As you say the problem is not in the names. I removed everything as you suggested - but still some messages do not get displayed on the input controls even though they are in the validation summary. The problem is that when you look at the generated html, the ones that do not have the message are marked as valid in the attributes even though they are not in the validation summary. very confusing!